# mysqli object has no method execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Been reading around and I can't find an accurate answer. I just want to query the database using a prepared statements but i'm getting:

Call to undefined method mysqli::execute()

This is what I have currently:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$conn->prepare("SELECT AccomodationID, PUPoint, PUTime, Entity_ID, Comments FROM ACCOMMODATION ORDER BY PUPoint ASC");
$conn->execute();
$conn->bind_result($AccomodationID, $PUPoint, $PUTime, $Entity_ID, $Comments);
$conn->store_result();
```

**EDIT**

Resolved. Big thanks to TML for the help. mysqli->prepare returns a `mysqli_stmt` object.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT AccomodationID, PUPoint, PUTime, Entity_ID, Comments FROM ACCOMMODATION ORDER BY PUPoint ASC");
```

I can then use methods of that object, like so:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($AccomodationID, $PUPoint, $PUTime, $Entity_ID, $Comments);
$stmt->store_result();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) *returns* a `mysqli_stmt` object. [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) is a method on that object, not on the original `mysqli` object.

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$conn->prepare("SELECT AccomodationID, PUPoint, PUTime, Entity_ID, Comments FROM ACCOMMODATION ORDER BY PUPoint ASC");
$stmt = $conn->execute();
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($AccomodationID, $PUPoint, $PUTime, $Entity_ID, $Comments);
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: I will show how to correct the code. Thanks for the explanation. Just what I needed